# When using tensorflow and numpy in one notebook: The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

When I try to run code using keras and numpy or keras and Matplotlib in one Jupyter notebook I always get the message: The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically. 
When I run the code in two different notebooks it works perfectly fine. I have installed it using anaconda and I am using macOS. I would really appreciate an answer, everything else I've found and tried so far did not work. Thank you!

Comment: Can you please share the reproducible code. Thanks!